# I need help determining lug removal tool

Tags: lug-nut

I bought a used vehicle. It came with Ultra Motorsport Hunter rims installed and no tool to remove the lug nuts. I am not even sure how to describe this - it doesn’t look exactly like the spline nut on my other vehicle. Is there any way to look up or determine what type of tool can remove these without buying an expensive assortment? [image]

Comment: It's possible that the tool you need is stored in the vehicle somewhere.  Have you searched?  It's also possible that the wheel manufacturer sold the locking lug nuts as well.  They may be able to provide you a replacement tool.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What vehicle are these on (year/make/model)? It would help to know this so we have an idea of what the lug size is for the vehicle. I did a Google search on "seven sided lug nuts" and came up with a plethora of options. I'm sure one of them would work for you. If I had the lug size, it would be fairly easy to track down what size of socket would be needed to get the proper replacement.

Comment: I wouldn't know for sure, but it appears [this set](https://www.walmart.com/ip/WINMAX-AUTOMOTIVE-TOOLS-Black-Locking-Lug-Nut-Master-Key-Set-Spline-Star-Hex-Style-Thin-Wall-Long-Lug-Key/760846418) probably has what you need. It has a variety of sockets. The center top one seems like what you'd need. If you got it and it doesn't have what you need, you could most likely return it for a refund.

Comment: If you go to an auto parts store, they may recognize the bolt and know what it is, or they may have a couple of sets and be willing to walk outside with you to figure out which set has the socket you need, then sell you just that set. Saves the time of buying & returning. You won't get that kind of service at Walmart or Amazon.

Comment: @FreeMan FWIW, I've done this. I've gone to two specialty tire shops and some auto part stores. No dice yet.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like a 6 spline lug nut key.
Sometimes the keys for this just slide onto the splines and on the other end just be a standard hex head that you'd fit your wrench onto. This might be the right one from Amazon, but I don't know the size:

Circuit Performance Large Black 6 Point Spline Truck SUV Tool Key https://a.co/d/isJMvWq

Might be best to measure it first though.

Edit:

Turns out there are seven splines from your picture. Thank you for catching that @Martin.

Here's a new link to what I think you would need. Be sure to measure yours though and make sure it will fit.
[7 Point Standard Spline Tool Key](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01LWPMYF5)

Comment: I count 7 splines